# List of sift descriptors to an NxN matrix

Tags: python, numpy, sift

I have a lot of sift descriptor from a dense-sift algorithm. Its an Array of N SIFT descriptor. One descriptor looks like this one:

```
[14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0, ...]
```

y Goal is to transform the descriptors to an NxN Matrix so i can use them like an image feature input for an Machine Learning Struktur. So in Short: I want to transform many 1d arrays to an 2d Array taking into account that the data points are split in the correct order.

Is there a way to work with np.vstack or is there a other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stack` and `reshape` and specify the desired axis like the following:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.ones((1, 128))
arr1 = arr1.reshape((4,4,8))

arr2 = np.ones((1, 128))
arr2 = arr2.reshape((4,4,8))


print(np.stack((arr1, arr2), axis=3).shape)
# (4, 4, 8, 2)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I would re-specify my description.  I have a sift descriptor which consists of an array with a length of 128. i would like to put this descriptor in the sift usual form (4x4x8). In the second step I would merge all transformed sift descriptors.

Comment: @john-mueller merge how?

Comment: The most important would be the first transformation from an array to a 4x4x8 array. The next step is currently not really relevant.